# Using bit datatype as part of composite primary key, good or bad?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, primary-key

I just wanted to check if using column of type of bit (SQL Server 2008) and a guid to form a composite primary keys is bad practise or not. i.e.

```
id1 (GUID) pk
id2 (GUID) pk
id3 (int) pk
isTrue (bit) pk
col1 (int)
col2 (datetime) 
...
```

I have 4 cols which makeup my composite pks.

Please advice if its good idea or not.

Comment: What exactly are your concerns? There is no problem with the datatype itself.

Comment: Is it really like that? I've seen a lot of designs where the desired semantic was "1 unique entry set to 1, as many as desired set to 0", but I can't think of any I've seen where it's 1 set to 1 and 1 set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no problem using this combination but only one suggestion here is to use NEWSEQUENTIALID() insted of newid() to populate id1 and id2.

Comment: I'd have thought it unlikely that either or both of those columns are generating their values through either function. If you're using such a function, a single column is sufficient to uniquely identify each row. This looks more like some kind of junction table between other tables where `id1` and `id2` stand as primary keys by themselves.

Comment: Yeah good point Damien_The_Unbeliever.I did not think abt that.Thanks for pointing it out